# Show that this submodule is not completely reducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $M = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{C} \\ \mathbb{C} \end{bmatrix}$.

Show that $M$ is not completely reducible as a left module over $R = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{C} & 0 \\ \mathbb{C} & \mathbb{C} \end{bmatrix}$.

I'm not sure how to tackle this? I can spot that $N = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \mathbb{C} \end{bmatrix}$ is a submodule of $M$, but how do I show that it has no complement in $M$?

I thought about checking if $\begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{C} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is not a submodule of $M$, but this isn't sufficient as there are plenty of other submodules.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be a nonzero submodule of $M$ and suppose
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \end{bmatrix} \in K
$$
with $x\ne0$. Then
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ \beta & \gamma \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \beta p+\gamma q \end{bmatrix}
$$
and we can obviously choose $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $\beta p+\gamma q$ is every complex number we fix. This shows $N\subseteq K$.

Comment: So why does it follow that $N$ doesn’t have a complement in $M$?

Comment: @theman It follows that $N$ is the unique minimal submodule of $M$. Hence $M$ is not the sum of simple submodules. But the other way is good as well: a complement should *not* contain $N$, but it can't.

Answer (score 0):

The subspaces of $M$ are of the form$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}az\\bz\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,z\in\mathbb{C}\right\},$$for some complex numbers $a$ and $b$. It is easy to see that, unless $a=0$, none of them is a submodule.